# Equations for HOMFLY polynomial of $(2,2k+1)$ Torus knots?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, knot-theory

Equations for HOMFLY polynomial of $(2,2k+1)$ Torus knots?

I'd appreciate a reference... Been looking around but can't find anything. $(2,2k+1)$ torus knots are a very well understood class of notes so I'm sure this formula is out there. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate this by studying the HOMFLY polynomial for tangles.  First, to set a convention, I'm going to use the HOMFLY polynomial with this skein relation:

[image: HOMFLY skein relation with a and z]

A fact about the skein relation is that every tangle can be reduced into a linear combination $L_0$ and $L_+$.  To that end, let's study the adding-a-right-hand-twist operator:

[image: adding a right-hand twist to basis elements]

With respect to the $\{L_0,L_+\}$ basis, then, the matrix of $T$ is
$$[T] = a^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & a^{-1} \\
a & z \end{bmatrix}.$$
This allows us to see what twisting something $k$ times would do by calculating $[T]^k$.

Another ingredient is closing a tangle:

[image: closing a tangle]

Since a right-hand twist $L_+$ is represented by the vector $(0,1)$, we have that the HOMFLY polynomial of a $T(2,2k+1)$ torus knot is
$$P(T(2,2k+1)) = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{a-a^{-1}}{z} & 1 \end{bmatrix}
[T]^{2k} \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

This matrix $[T]$ is diagonalizable, so you can compute this matrix power as
$$P(T(2,2k+1)) =
a^{-2k} \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{a-a^{-1}}{z} & 1 \end{bmatrix}
A
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{z-\sqrt{4+z^2}}{2} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{z+\sqrt{4+z^2}}{2}
\end{bmatrix}^{2k}
A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
with
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{z+\sqrt{4+z^2}}{2a} & -\frac{z-\sqrt{4+z^2}}{2a} \\ 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Note that it doesn't matter which branch cut you take to compute the square roots --- all that matters is that the square roots are negatives of one another.  It's probably best to just interpret them purely symbolically (i.e., use only the fact that the square of $\sqrt{4+z^2}$ is $4+z^2$).

After some simplification, we can get
$$P(T(2,2k+1)) =
\frac{(2-a^2(2+z x))x^{2k} + (-2+a^2(2+z y))y^{2k}}{4^ka^{2k+2}z(y-x)}$$
where
\begin{align*}
x&=z-\sqrt{4+z^2} & y&=z+\sqrt{4+z^2}.
\end{align*}
I've checked that this expression matches a table of HOMFLY polynomials for $1\leq k\leq 8$.

I wouldn't be surprised if someone already calculated it in this way, but unfortunately I'm not aware of a reference, other than things like [The Knot Atlas](http://katlas.org/wiki/36_Torus_Knots) and [KnotInfo](https://knotinfo.math.indiana.edu/), which contain HOMFLY polynomials for individual knots.

**Edit:** After much more simplification, I got it into this form:
$$P(T(2,2k+1)) =
a^{-2k-1} \sum_{n=0}^k \left(
a\binom{k+n+1}{2n+1} - a^{-1}\binom{k+n}{2n+1}
\right) z^{2n}$$

---

**Edit:** I found some potential references.

Duzhin and Shkolnikov explain how to compute HOMFLY polynomials for 2-bridge knots (closures of rational tangles).  Corollary 1 in section 4 purports to give a formula for $T(2,n)$ torus links, but it doesn't seem to match the tables: [http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~duzhin/papers/rat_knots_e3.pdf](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/%7Eduzhin/papers/rat_knots_e3.pdf)

Labastida and Marino use Chern-Simons gauge theory to obtain a formula for all torus links.  See Theorem 3.1: https://cds.cern.ch/record/259127/files/9402093.pdf

Comment: Kyle Miller, thank you so much, I was hoping you would come to the rescue. I have a further question, if I may: In some papers, for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5886, the HOMFLY skein is defined by replacing $z$ with $q-q^{-1}$, what is the motivation for this?? Once this is done, the HOMFLY polynomial is no longer a laurent polynomial in 2 indeterminants, because now coefficients of the form $q^k-q^{-k}$ are allowed in the denominator. 

can you give me some insight on this??

Comment: The HOMFLY invariant can be parameterized in many different ways, and all that seems to be essential is that it's a two-variable function.  I think the $q-q^{-1}$ comes from deriving the HOMFLY invariant from the representation theory of quantum groups (though, if I remember correctly, in the original HOMFLY paper, Ocneanu's approach also had such a factor, and it came from Hecke algebras and some trigonometric functions).  A nice skein theoretic approach is to assert the relation $x L_+ + y L_- + z L_0=0$, and then the HOMFLY invariant is a homogeneous Laurent polynomial of three variables.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, you've been a big help. If you have time, I have another question: I'm now trying to learn about the colored Jones polynomial. There is a paper called "the sl3 colored jones polynomial" by Hugh Morton and some other authors. Now, it was my impression that the colored Jones polynomial corresponds to representations of $SU(2)$. It seems there is a lot of differing lingo in the literature.

Do you have any basic insights or references you could send me for an intro to the colored Jones polynomial? Thanks you are the best